# Conditional jsonpath expressions not working in groovy script, jmeter

Tags: dictionary, groovy, jmeter, conditional-statements, jsonpath

```
Conditional jsonpath expression: 
    $.[?(@.identifier == "369")]..columns.[?(@.type == "relationship")].token
```

- Problem 01: groovy script in jsr233 post processor not parsing the jsonpath expression.
- Problem 02: I need to loop identifier value in groovy or beanshell and fetch multiple array.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

//String idval = parsedJson.sections[1].id

//String idval = parsedJson.[?(@.identifier == "369")]..columns.[?(@.type == "relationship")].token //trail 01 -failed at .[

String idval = parsedJson./[?(@.identifier == "369")]/..columns./[?(@.type == "relationship")]/.token  //trail 02 -no such property: columns for class

log.info(""+idval);
```

Comment: groovy.json.JsonSlurper does not support jsonpath but with groovy you could write expressions close to jsonpath. Share original json and expected result, and somebody will help you to write groovy expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JSON Path expressions with the [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html), consider either using [find()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find())/ [findAll()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll()) functions on the returned collection or moving to [JsonPath](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0) instead

```
def idval = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '?($..sections[@.identifier == "369")]..columns.[?(@.type == "relationship")]')
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)